# Multiple URL redirect maps for different domains in Nginx

Tags: nginx

I have an nginx instance serving a couple of website. The way the config is set up is that `/etc/nginx.conf.d` includes a few `.conf` files from `/etc/nginx/conf.d`, one per website. I believe this is pretty standard.

Each of the `.conf` files has a `map` section to map URIs, and a `server` section that uses the `map`, like this:

```
map $request_uri $redirect_uri {
  /foo /bar;
}

server {
  ...
  if ($redirect_uri) {
    return 302 $redirect_uri;
  }
  ...
}
```

It took me a while to understand why the aliases from one website were using the redirect table of a different website: because all these are included in the same scope, each `map` redefines the `$redirect_uri` variable!

Ideally, I'd want to put each `map` within the scope of the `server` that is going to use it, but nginx complains that `"map" directive is not allowed here in <file>`. The workaround I found is to give a different name to each map variable, but this is manual and error-prone.

**TLDR**: How do I keep separate redirect maps scoped to the server that will use them?

Comment: Good question. But, your workaround is the only way, from what I know.